# Can I tell if an Amazon SQS message is still in flight?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Given an Amazon SQS message, is there a way to tell if it is still in flight via the API? Or, would I need to note the timestamp when I receive the message, subtract that from the current time, and check if that is less than the visibility timeout?

Comment: there are some things you can do indirectly with: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ChangeMessageVisibility.html but usually something else is not right  if you need to do these kind of checks.

Comment: Did you mean these indirect checks indicate something else is not right? Or that having to check whether a message is in flight in any way indicates that something is not right?

Comment: having to check directly that a message is in flight means that your application is brittle.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The normal flow for using Amazon Simple Queueing Service (SQS) is:

- A message is **pushed** onto a queue using `SendMessage` (it can remain in the queue for up to 14 days)
- An application uses `ReceiveMessage` to **retrieve** a message from the queue (no guarantee of first-in-first-out)
- When the application has **finished processing** the message, it calls `DeleteMessage` (it can also call `ChangeMessageVisibility` to extend the time until it times-out)
- If the application does not delete the message within a pre-configured time period, SQS makes the message **reappear** on the queue
- If a message is retrieved from the queue more than a pre-configured number of times, the message can be moved to a **Dead Letter queue**

**It is not possible to obtain information about a specific message.** Rather, the application asks for a message (or a batch of messages), upon which the message becomes invisible (or 'in flight'). This also gives access to a `ReceiptHandle` that can be used with `DeleteMessage` or `ChangeMessageVisibility`.

The closest option is to call `GetQueueAttributes`. The value for `ApproximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisible` will indicate the **number of in-flight messages** but it will not give insight into a *particular* message.