# SQS handle strategy using groupId and threadpool?

Tags: multithreading, design-patterns, architecture, message-queue, amazon-sqs

I am in process of designing sqs FIFO handling strategy, so trying to do it in a right way. Faced with few fundamental questions.

For example i have in queue:

- 100 messages with groupid "`group1_100`"
- 5 messages with  "`group2_5`"
- 1 message with "`group3_1`"
- 1 message with "`group4_1`"

**Example of handle :**

I requested 10 messages using longpooling :

1.1) Can i be sure that i'll receive 10 (max of requested) messages pre request on retrieve if there are more, than 10 messages of same group.

1.2) May sqs returns me 7 messages from `group1_100`, 2 from `group2_5` and 1 from `group4_1`?

if yes :

1.2.1) for example, handling this 7 messages of group1_100 will take 10 seconds. So using thread pool 3 messages from `group2_5` and `group4_1` already handled in parallel - so i saying to sqs that they were handled so :

1.2.2) making another one request to sqs (to not wait until 7 messages from `group1_100` finished). So

1.2.2.1) Is it possible, that i can receive messages from `group1_100` (that should be handled after first 7 = in right order)?  (assume, that no, because sqs guarantee us that it will be retrieved strongly in right order). Am i right?

In case if 1.2 is "yes" i need to control different "groupid" handle to prevent situation, when my processors will work only for "group1_100" even if they were first from "group/time" point of view, right? To prevent theoretic attack like "we are as a client will send you a lot of messages with one groupId, and you'll need to take us all your handle processors".

2. So it may happen in case of single thread handling, right?
3. **And may it be resolved by next strategy?** :

Making request to get 10 messages -> devide them to n groups (grouping by groupid) and starting handle them in parralel. When all messages from "group" handled - making "batch" notify to sqs about finishing -> in parralel start fetching another one pack of messages to handle (depending on/checking constant total_handling_messages_limit_at_time) and start handle them in same way syncing fetching to not make it too many times per second/minute.

So it will allow us to split handle inside one worker using threadpool, and not to stack with "long running" tasks with "one groupid".

Am i right in general, guys? Maybe i something missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Made some investigations here, so answering for most of them :

> 1.1) Can i be sure that i'll receive 10 (max of requested) messages pre request on retrieve if there are more, than 10 messages of same
> group.

No, queue may return 9. Or 8. So fewer, than you requested even if messages available to retrieve

> 1.2) May sqs returns me 7 messages from group1_100, 2 from group2_5 and 1 from group4_1?

Absolutely yes

> 1.2.1) for example, handling this 7 messages of group1_100 will take 10 seconds. So using thread pool 3 messages from group2_5 and group4_1 already handled in parallel - so i saying to sqs that they were handled so :

> 1.2.2) making another one request to sqs (to not wait until 7 messages from group1_100 finished). So

> 1.2.2.1) Is it possible, that i can receive messages from group1_100 (that should be handled after first 7 = in right order)? (assume, that no, because sqs guarantee us that it will be retrieved strongly in right order). Am i right?

Assuming is right (so answer is no). If your handler retrieved at least one message from `group_1_100` - no one handler will not get from queue messages of this group while this one message will not be handled (or it returned by visibility timeout by sqs itself), so be carefull with visibility timeout - in case you will not handle message correctly - all messages of group may hang up for a timeout time.

> In case if 1.2 is "yes" i need to control different "groupid" handle to prevent situation, when my processors will work only for "group1_100" even if they were first from "group/time" point of view, right? To prevent theoretic attack like "we are as a client will send you a lot of messages with one groupId, and you'll need to take us all your handle processors".

> So it may happen in case of single thread handling, right?

In general :

1. you don't need to control it, because of all messages with same groupid will be "freezed" while you are handling first n from them and other handlers will get messages from other groups.(see prev answer)
2. You absolutely 100% need to split it by *threads* or *n consumers*, do not handle it in synchronious way by one consumer.

> And may it be resolved by next strategy? :

Seems like yes. Excepting :

> and not to stack with "long running" tasks with "one groupid".

as mentioned above.

Also would like to provide additional info to note :

1. messages in groups always sorted by timestamp **within** this group
2. you can't assume, that groups will be received in right timestamp order. so for example if group1 was posted at 10:00, group2 in 10:01 and group3 in 10:02 - no any guarantee that you will receive group1, then group2, then group3 - it may return 5 from group2 and 5 from group 3 for example :) Also, group order is also not strict per request (only messages in each group)
3. if you have 100 messages in group1,and retrieve only one from it - other 99 will wait while you handle this one.

Also, some usefull info here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31799733/1151741

ps. Correct me please if i am wrong somewhere.

Hope it will help someone